# How to invert Airplane mode light on laptop?

Tags: networking, network-manager, indicator, airplane-mode

On my laptop, the airplane mode light/indicator is inverted in Ubuntu.

The light is on when airplane mode is off and off when airplane mode is on. The hardware works perfectly fine with Ubuntu. The airplane mode works fine, just the light/indicator is opposite. It works correctly in windows though.

How can I switch this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Some laptops may contain hardware that is meant to be used with Windows; these hardware may have settings hidden somewhere in the BIOS. They may not work or misbehave on Linux. If your laptop came with Windows on it, go to the BIOS, and change from "Advanced" or "Windows Compatibility Mode" to "Legacy" or "Normal", or something like that.

Note that this solution may not be possible if there is no option in the BIOS for that particular hardware.

Comment: Although the laptop did not come with windows pre-installed, the drivers available are for windows only. But, the airplane mode works fine, all the hardware works fine, Just the indicator light acts opposite to the way it does in windows. I am sure there will be something in Ubuntu that controls this light/indicator

Comment: Well then I don't know how to solve it... :)